# Non-optimized sorting algorithm, which one to use?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

The last element of the sorted array is replaced with a random value that does not occur in the array. Which classical, ie non-optimized, version of the sorting algorithm should be used to sort this array as efficiently as possible?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is sorted except for the last element, no sorting is needed.

Simply remove take the last element form the array, and insert it at the right location. Takes **O(log n)** time to find the location to insert it at.

---

**P.s.**
As pointed out by  @Henry the actual inserting in an array (at least in most programming-languages) will take another **O(n)** time because it most likely means to shift all elements one to the right to free the position we want to insert our element.

Comment: to clarfy: the actual insertion takes O(n)

Comment: @Henry: I said nothing different. As I wrote: Finding the position takes O(log n) the costs to actually insert the element depends on the array-implementation which results in most programming-languages in O(n) costs for the insert.